# Calculate the mean of a column for each batch of n rows in R

Tags: r

Suppose I have a data frame like this...

```
> head(x)
  round       value
1     1  0.37207016
2     2  0.51954917
3     3 -0.70684976
4     4  0.76105557
5     5  0.09252876
6     6 -2.42223178
> tail(x)
    round      value
95     95 -0.6799075
96     96 -0.4109732
97     97  0.9740048
98     98 -0.8877499
99     99  0.1501041
100   100 -0.5415825
```

...and I want to get the mean `value` over each 10-round interval. I've posted one answer below, but a common thing to want to do, so is there is a more straightforward way?

Comment: There are many options available, `aggregate` gets the summary mean for the group.  If you need a mean value column, you could use `ave`.  Other options include `dplyr` (with `mutate` or `summarise`) and `data.table` (using `:=` or `list(`)

Comment: An option using `data.table` `setDT(x)[, list(MeanValue=mean(value)), list(batch=gl(nrow(x), 10, nrow(x)))]`

Answer (score 1):

I can do some gymnastics to create a data frame with an extra column for the "batch" index, and then group by that to calculate the mean.

```
> y <- data.frame(x$round, x$value, rep(1:10, each=10))
> colnames(y) <- c("round","value", "batch")
> head(y)
  round       value batch
1     1  0.37207016     1
2     2  0.51954917     1
3     3 -0.70684976     1
4     4  0.76105557     1
5     5  0.09252876     1
6     6 -2.42223178     1
> tail(y)
    round      value batch
95     95 -0.6799075    10
96     96 -0.4109732    10
97     97  0.9740048    10
98     98 -0.8877499    10
99     99  0.1501041    10
100   100 -0.5415825    10
> tapply(y$value, y$batch, mean)
          1           2           3           4           5           6 
-0.13784753 -0.15969468  0.41346173  0.09019686 -0.26467052 -0.29677632 
          7           8           9          10 
 0.06489254  0.17609739  0.35029525 -0.19669901
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using modulo division. Need to subtract 1 to get first group of size 10:

```
 tapply(y$yvalue, (nrow(x)-1) %/% 10, mean)
```